# Java autosubmit random; sometimes work, sometimes not

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have a site I am developing where a page will advance to a different page within an iframe after so many seconds. I have a manual version where you have to click next. I am developing an auto version where it would advance to the next page after so many seconds. Using document.forms["advance"].submit(); where advance is the name of the form for the "next" button.

The manual version always works when clicking "Next". The auto version, using the code above will advance, but sometimes displays a blank page in the frame instead of what should be the next page. When the timer is done, it will then advance to the next page; sometimes another blank page, sometimes the proper page. There seems to be no rhyme or reason to it. Not every other page or two or three blank pages in a row. Completely random.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: There is a reason for it, but there's nothing we can do to help without your code for the "next" button, the form, and the timeout code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out. Came down to the human hand (manual) versus autosubmit. Autosubmit needed some type of delay to let scripts load prior to the page refresh. So instead of using this:

```
document.forms["advance"].submit();
```

Changed it to this:

```
setInterval(function(){document.forms["advance"].submit()},2000);
```

I guess a two second delay prior to the autosubmit made all the difference.